# Can I have a Kantonian and Alolan form of the same pokemon in a team?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

For example's sake, I have a Kanto Ninetales for special sweeping with a Sunny Day/Flamethrower combo and an Alolan Ninetales for laying down Aurora Veil with Snow Warning to set up for a buff sweeper.

I know most competitions have a rule against having multiple pokemon of the same species in a team.

Would using two Kantonian and Alolan form of a pokemon (like my two Ninetales) break this rule because their technically the same species or do they count as separate pokemon?

Answer (score 2):

Smogon rules ban using more than one Pokemon with the same national dex number. Different forms are stil the same pokemon so, under Smogon rules, you would not be allowed both Ninetales on the same team.

Other tournaments may use different interpretations, but this is the most commonly used ruleset.